# Bidirectional OneToMany relation causing maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 tablels Foo, Bar and Foo_x_Bar_Status, in my service im trying to create new record for Foo_x_Bar_Status. Im fetching managed object of Foo and managed object of Bar, then im creating new object of FooBarStatus and set previously fetched Foo and Bar objects on it. Then im trying to persist my newly created FooBarStatus wirh `entityManager.merge()` (it needs to be merge as i need to return FooBarStatus managed object without searching for it again), however this merge fails with message: `java.sql.SQLException: - ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded`, how can i solve this issue?

P.S. i know i can just remove collections from Foo and Bar and access is via dedicated service, however it is essential for me to have this bidirectional relation

Foo:

```
@Entity(name = "Foo")
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FOO_SEQ")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "foo", orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<FooBarStatus> fooBarStatus;
}
```

Bar:

```
@Entity(name = "Bar")
@Table(name = "BAR")
public class BAR implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BAR_SEQ")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "bar", orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<FooBarStatus> fooBarStatus;
}
```

FooBarStatus:

```
@Entity(name = "FooBarStatus")
@Table(name = "Foo_x_Bar_Status")
public class FooBarStatus implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FOO_BAR_STATUS_SEQ")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID", nullable = false)
private Foo foo;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID", nullable = false)
private Bar bar;
```

Service

```
@Service
public class FooBarStatusServiceImpl implements FooBarStatus {

@Autowired
private FooRepository fooRepository;

@Autowired
private BarRepository barRepository;

@Autowired
private FooBarStatusReposiotry fooBarStatusReposiotry;

@Override
public FooBarStatus createFooBarStatus(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
//make foo nd bar managed
foo = fooRepository.createFoo(foo);
bar = barRepository.createBar(bar);

FooBarStatus fooBarStatus = new FooBarStatus();
fooBarStatus.setFoo(foo);
fooBarStatus.setBar(bar);

return fooBarStatusReposiotry.createFooBarStatus(fooBarStatus);
}
}
```

FooBarStatusReposioty:

```
@Repository
public class FooBarStatusReposiotyImpl implements FooBarStatusReposioty {

    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public FooBarStatus createFooBarStatus(FooarStatus fooBarStatus){
    return entityManager.merge(fooBarStatus);
}
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
2018-11-28 16:43:02 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor154.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
at com.iwork.server.defautmodel.User.hashCode(User.java:20)
at com.iwork.server.defautmodel.UserNotification.hashCode(UserNotification.java:11)
at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:327)
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:234)
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:221)
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:194)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
at com.application.server.defautmodel.Bar.hashCode(Bar.java:20)
at com.application.server.defautmodel.Foo.hashCode(Foo.java:11)
at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
```

the stacktrace is much longer but it seems like its looping.
Foo.java:11 and Bar.java:20 are pointing to `@Data` annotation from Lombok

Comment: Firstly, every entity must have an ID and FooBarStatus doesn't. Secondly, use entityManager.persist() which *"Make an instance managed and persistent."* so you don't have to query again. Fix these basic issues and see where you're at.

Comment: @AlanHay Foo and Bar are simplified versions of my classes just to represent the issue, of course they do have Id's. Please provide some context why persist should work differently from merge in this case? it seems like a blind shoot

Comment: Sorry I can't guess what is wrong. Why  don't you post all the relevant code and use the API properly as a first step.

Comment: @AlanHay added full code with repository, changed merge to persist, it did not solve the problem.

Comment: What statement does it actually throw the exception on? This issue doesn't seem related to what you've shown here; it seems more likely a problem in the test environment you have setup for the foo and bar repository classes, as a simple merge should only use one or two more queries to check the FooBarStatus existence before inserting it.

Comment: @Chris added stacktrace

Comment: Looks like you are doing something funky with your hashcode methods, causing a whole bunch of queries to get triggered.  You seem to do this on Bar, foo AND UserNotification and User classes.  Don't access lazy or any relationship in a hashcode or equality check, especially if you are using maps or sets which use them.

Comment: The curse of Lombok in a JPA context: let me add this one little annotation which will create an equals and hashcode based on all fields of my class and load half my database every when one of those methods is called.

Comment: As a starting point then, remove the  `@Data` annotation from all entities and, if required, add Lombok's  `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations.

Comment: @Chris thank you, your suggestion solved my issue. I will post solution as na answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Chris in comment, root cause was that usage of `@Data` annotation generated a HashCode calculation method and since Foo, Bar and FooBarStatus had lazy initialized attributes with bidirectional relation, hash calculation attempted to fetch data and lopped back infinitely. Since all Foo, Bar and FooBarStatus are unique by id's it is not necerssary to include joined attribtes in hash calculation. Therefore as per https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode i have added @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude to bidirectional lazy initialized attributes which excluded the from hash calculation. Example below:

```
@Entity(name = "Foo")
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FOO_SEQ")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "foo", orphanRemoval = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
private Set<FooBarStatus> fooBarStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by Connections, Statements, and ResultSets left open. Example,

```
Connection with = getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement 
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery ();
```

So, you just close the

```
rs.close ();
ps.close ();
con.close ();
```

option is to use a try {} catch (e) {} finally {} and close in the finally

Comment: In the case of hibernate you have to close the Session

Comment: Do you get Entity Manager via dependency injection, like EJB and @PersistenceContext annotation or you use EntityManagerFactory? If you use annotation it should not happen.

Comment: @AlanJhone how to do so? i thought it was handled by ``@Transactional`` annotation

Comment: @AkkaJaworek I'm using org.hibernate.Session, try doing this in your persistence class:

public void saveOuUpdate (Object obj) {
    Session session = getSession ();
    session.saveOrUpdate (obj);
    session.flush ();
    session.clear ();
}